# RDS Postgresql High CPU and ClientRead waits

Tags: postgresql

I am having the same issue as in this question:
[Blocking on idle connections on ClientRead for parametrized queries (bindings) during high traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538709/blocking-on-idle-connections-on-clientread-for-parametrized-queries-bindings-d/64128352#64128352)

Basically we are hitting high CPU on our RDS postgres(11)  instances with very minimal amount of traffic. All of the idle transactions are showing as wait type  Client:ClientRead   The only way that the CPU drops is if I do the horrible thing of killing the transactions manually.

We are using Framework created sql to access an rds postgresql (11) db. The transactions are remaining open by design of our developers. We are having the same issues with CPU on the instance as in the initial issue on this thread. I Keep getting pushing back when I explain that Postgres is not designed to work this way and I need some better explanation of how this works than I am able to give as a newbie and a tangible suggestion for a fix or alternative.

Comment: The other question you linked to had low CPU usage, not high CPU usage.  Client:ClientRead does not consume CPU.  What are you seeing that makes you think it does?  You are probably misinterpreting your monitoring tool output.

Comment: It could be that there are many very short queries that a select to `pg_stat_activity` never catches. Are you talking about transactions or connections? Long transactions are clearly evil. Anyway, this question needs much more information for a useful answer.

Comment: I had the same exact problem and solved it in the question you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66573418/4719679. Also, @jjanes is right, this does not change anything about the CPU load.